# How does qemu-kvm interact with kvm module?

Tags: qemu, kvm

I'm trying to read qemu-kvm and kvm modules and it is quite hard to understand the following:

```
How does qemu-kvm interact with kvm kernel module?
```

Any explanations or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

qemu-kvm interacts with KVM via `ioctl` types ([reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/api.txt)):

- The `KVM_CREATE_VM` ioctl, sent to a file descriptor for `/dev/kvm`, creates a VM file descriptor.
- The `KVM_CREATE_VCPU`, sent to a VM file descriptor, creates a VCPU file descriptor.
- The `KVM_SET_REGS` ioctl, sent to a VCPU file descriptor, initializes the registers.

More information is passed between QEMU and KVM by `mmap`-ing the VCPU file descriptor. Finally, the guest runs with the `KVM_RUN` ioctl sent to a VCPU file descriptor, until the kernel needs QEMU to do something (typically emulate some piece of virtual hardware).